# How can I write a good answer?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes an answer needs to be formatted with math formulas. I think that we should create a tutorial for new members on how to write a good answer. As in my case, I don't know how to write those formulas. Where can I learn that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a tutorial and links to more information on the Mathematics Meta site: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/228959).

The Help Center page [Editing Help](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) mentions [this website](http://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) as another reference.

Comment: i have a little bit of knowledge in latex, good answer!

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point for your questions headline would be [this help center page](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). However, this is just a guideline that does not mention and explain the specific tools you can use to write good answers.

Since your text focusses mainly on math formulas: Many (not all) Stack Exchange sites support MathJax which gives you the ability to insert LaTeX formulas into your text. You can either use inline equations with `$...$` to include symbols and formulas directly into your text. For example this one $a^2 \cdot \sqrt(x)$ was created with `$a^2 \cdot \sqrt(x)$`. Alternatively, you can write formulas in a separate line using `$$...$$`. For example:
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \gamma x^2 \;\textrm{d}x$$
This was generated with `$$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \gamma x^2 \;\textrm{d}x$$`. Note that the syntax to start and end the math environment might differ slightly on different SE pages. If you don't know how to code in LaTeX you have to search for it on the internet since it is an external tool and there are already a lot of tutorials out there (Or simply follow the links of Glorfindels answer).

**Hint:**

If you see some special technique or tool in other questions/answers and you don't know how to use it a good trick that might help you is just hitting the edit button. It will give you access to the complete source code of the post and you can examine how the feature of interest was implemented. Just watch out that you don't accidentally submit an edit.

Comment: i will use the edit button to create my question